# Cannot open include file: 'mvvm/dialog.h'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mvvm

I am developing a application for 4kvideodownloader. But when I run the code, visual studio  C++ has a error **"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mvvm/dialog.h': No such file or directory
"**
Can you help me with this error, please?

Comment: I think the message "No such file or directory" is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Visual Studio is not hiding anything from you. It simply cannot find the file specified. So you will need to check if all the include paths to your library are set up properly within your project's settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the parent directory of the folder "mvvm" in your include path.